# ASP.net - How to serve files stored outside web application that are on the same machine?

Tags: asp.net, upload, static-files

For example, the URL is `http://files.mysite.com/images/mypic.jpg.`

I would typically store that in the `/images` folder at the root of the web application, which makes the `/images` folder a part of my application.

I want to keep those files in `C:/images`, so the actual physical path to the image is `C:/images/mypic.jpg`.

What do I need to code in my app and/or do in IIS so that the browser will display that image when I point it to that URL?

I have control of folders outside my web application because I am developing on a local machine, and once deployed, it'll be to a server I'll have full control of.

Comment: You would need to stream the file from code.  For example, create a resource (handler, page, controller action, whatever you're using) which accepts some query string value to indicate what file to return.  That resource would then read the file from the disk and stream it to the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to restrict access to the files, you can create a [virtual directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx) named "images" that has a physical path of `c:\images`.

Once it is set up, a request for `http://files.mysite.com/images/mypic.jpg` will return the image stored at `c:\images\mypic.jpg`.

A PowerShell script like this one ought to do it:

```
New-WebVirtualDirectory -Site "Default Web Site" -Name "images" -PhysicalPath "c:\images"
```

If you have any trouble getting the files back, make sure you have mapped the file name extensions and MIME types in IIS management console.